# Enterprise Architect: Automatically add dependencies in class diagram

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I imported my Java code in Enterprise Architect with the code engineering tool. If I add a class in the class diagram editor (UML) it automatically adds the associations and the generalizations but not the dependencies. Is it possible to setup EA that it also includes the existing dependencies from source code (local variables, parameters etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one option you can set which controls this in EA 10: look at Tools -- Options -- Source Code Engineering. The last of the list of check boxes is called "Create dependencies for operation returns and parameter types."

This solves the problem as far as parameters are concerned (you'd have to reimport the code, of course), but I haven't tested it to see how it deals with local variables. I'm guessing it doesn't create dependencies for those.